# Dead key not working with konsole, yakuake

Tags: keyboard-layout, qt, input-method, dead-keys

After `setxkbmap fr`, dead keys do not work under `konsole` and `yakuake` (typing the dead key `^` immediately prints a `^`, rather than wait for the next character), while they work in `xterm`.  The font I'm using supports them, and it is possible to input them e.g. in vim using digraphs.
Looking for a fix, thanks.

Comment: Could be [this bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=318151), or just some similar symptoms. Does anything on [this page](https://userbase.kde.org/ComposeKey) help? What version of KDE are you using, under which distribution?

Comment: I don't think it's the same bug: even if I `setxkbmap fr` and try immediately on a new `konsole` instance, this fails.

Not sure how your other link can help, I do not intend to use the compose key and don't see anything about dead keys in the advanced keyboard settings.

This is with KDE 4.14.3 under Arch.

Comment: The internal mechanisms for dead keys are very similar to those for a Compose key (sequences of keypresses that start with Compose or with dead_xxx are translated to a single character), so it's worth trying.

Answer (score 1):

Had that problem too (with a French keyboard). I found no solution to it with the default input method installed by KDE (**XIM**) - and I'm not enough of a system wizard to tweak it -, but I found a workaround by using another input method : **ibus**.

Here's what worked for me:

1. Install im-config, a package that allows you to change the system input method :

   ```
   apt-get install im-config zenity
   ```
2. Install ibus and qt-config (libpinyin also allows you to get a method
   for entering Chinese characters using a pinyin transliteration - for those who are interested - that's what the two last packages in this line are for) :

   ```
   apt-get install ibus ibus-qt4 qt4-qtconfig ibus-libpinyin libpinyin-utils
   ```
3. Set the base parameters of **ibus** (e.g. your national keyboard) :

   ```
   ibus-setup
   ```
4. Tell the system that **ibus** should be the default input method in software using the **Qt** graphic library (that is, all native KDE applications like Konsole, etc.):

   ```
   qtconfig-qt4
   ```
5. Use **im-config** to choose **ibus** as your default input method for all X11 applications:

   ```
   im-config
   ```
6. To make those changes recognized in every future X11 session, add these lines to your **~/.xsessionrc** file (or create it if you don't have one yet):

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   export GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
   export XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
   export QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
   ibus-daemon -drx
   ```
7. In my case (it might not be yours), because I'm using **tcsh** and not **bash** as the default shell in my **Konsole** sessions, and because for whichever reason X11 failed to read **.xsessionrc** at every new startup, I also had to add this line to the **.tcshrc** shell startup file:

   ```
   sh $HOME/.xsessionrc
   ```
8. Finally, in the **IBus** panel (that should now appear in the system tray), in the "Preferences" panel, "Advanced" tab, be sure to check the box "Use system keyboard layout", so that the keyboard layout used corresponds to what you have already chosen (and so that any additional options, e.g. position of the Compose Key, is taken into account).

Don't know why there was no simpler solution, and why the default input method does not take the dead keys mechanism into account (I checked in **xev**: the events were correctly sent by X11 to XIM, but Qt applications just ignored it!). Well anyway, I'm happy with the workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed solution.  However, I switched a while ago to using XKB (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_KeyBoard_extension) and it works fine with me, so I cannot easily check that your proposed solution works.  If anyone else confirms that it works, I will happily accept it.

Comment: Hey Antony, I am having the same problem with debian+kde, dead keys are working in Firefox and other non kde program but not in yakuake/kontact, etc... Could you answer your own response explaining what you did exactly to "switch to XKB?".

Comment: This answer could give a hint too: https://askubuntu.com/questions/619815/combining-keys-e-g-e-%C3%AB-not-working-in-kde-applications-dead-keys